# React re-renders component unnecessary after prop change

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-select

So I have reducer `autocomplete` that stores all options loaded throught `react-select`. I also have two components - `<Parent />` and `<Modal />`. Both of them are connected to redux state to receive `autocomplete` props, because both of them have its own `<AsyncSelect />` component.

`Select` that is children of `<Parent />` component, receives options from reducer: `autocomplete.labels`. Second `Select` component that is children of `<Modal />`, receives options from reducer: `autocomplete.differentLabels`.

Now, when I'm using `Select` that is children of `Modal`, whole `Parent` component is re-rendered, even if there is no jsx dependent on `autocomplete`. Is this expected behavior? Because of this re-rendering, performance decreases.

Maybe should I divide `labels` and `differentLabels` into separate reducers?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution can be to use the shouldComponentUpdate to compare the current props to previous props and do some logic there to prevent unnecessary update.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (this.props.myProp !== nextProps.myProp) {
        // Your logic
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `shouldComponentUpdate` instead of `componentDidUpdate `? Reason being `componentDidUpdate` will check for any prop changes and then perform something, whereas `shouldComponentUpdate` will just check for the prop and then allow component to update based on the condition.

Comment: Is it neccessary to write own `shouldComponentUpdate` method? I tried using PureComponent, but it didn't work as expected. There is only one place in my component where I'm using `autocomplete` reducer - and it's callback for `react-select`:
`const { labels } = this.props.autocomplete; callback(labels);`

Comment: @AmanshuKataria Yes you are totally right. I was meant to write shouldComponentUpdate but I don't know how I mistakenly typed it as componentDidUpdate. Nice catch. LOL.